# How to extract and format specific values from a string

Tags: php

We have files uploaded to our server in a specific format that indicates a version and build date, ex: **5_5_61__20180828.dav**

The first group of numbers represents the version `5_5_61`, and the last group of numbers represents the build date `20180828` and then `.dav` is just the file extension.

How would we be able to extract and format this file name to appear like this:

```
Version: 5.5.61 Build Date: 08/28/2018
```

I've been trying different variations of this snippet of code but can't seem to figure out the proper method:

```
$file = '5_5_61__20180828.dav';
echo substr($file, strpos($file , "_") + 1);
```

I should note that I am willing to change the file names if there's an easier way to achieve the final result using a different naming convention for the files.

Comment: If you're sure the filename will always be in the same format, i would use a regular expression. `/(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)__(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the versions and dates are separated by `__` (two underscores), it's quite straight forward.

First split the string on `__` (two underscores) -  that will give you the version, and the date with extension. Explode the last part again to separate date from extension. Then replace `_` (one underscore) with `.` on your version, and print it all.

Since `20180828` isn't a standard date-format for `strtotime()` functions, use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to create a date-object.

```
$filename = '5_5_61__20180828.dav';
$parts = explode("__", $filename);
$parts2 = explode(".", $parts[1]);

$version = str_replce("_", ".", $parts[0]);
$date = $parts2[0];
$extension = $parts2[1];

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd", $date)->format("m/d/Y");

echo "Version: $version. Build Date: $date";
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/4Lk2T

Comment: The second explode (.) can be replaced with a substr since the date is fixed in length

Comment: Fair point, that'll be a little more efficient too. Can probably reduce this whole split ordeal into a regex as well.

Comment: Yes, regex is possible, but not sure it will be faster. (But then again, I don't think this code will run thousands of times). But I just commented since it may make the code slightly cleaner to add the substr in the DateTime line than a separate line. All in all, +1

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Or just `$parts = explode("__", pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME));`

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/a5Vudv

```
$file = '5_5_61__20180828.dav';
$version =  str_replace("_", ".", substr($file, 0, -14));
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd", substr($file, -12, 8))->format("m/d/Y");
echo 'Version: ' . $version . ' Build Date: '. $d;
```